# I get an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, async-await

When trying to return all comments, as well as replies to comments, I ran into the problem

Example template:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
    "content": "comment",
    "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
    "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
    "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:04.391Z",
    "replyId": [
        {
          "id": "cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd",
          "content": "comment",
          "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
          "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
          "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:22.663Z",
          "replyId": [
              {
                "id": "dee96b97-cd45-4a09-a27d-985617cc5a16",
                "content": "comment",
                "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
                "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
                "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:35.204Z",
                "replyId": "cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd",
                "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
              }
            ],
          "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
        },
        {
          "id": "d61e0049-9075-4f25-8f6d-65ed61e245a8",
          "content": "comment",
          "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
          "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
          "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:21.271Z",
          "replyId": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
          "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
        },
        {
          "id": "cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd",
          "content": "comment",
          "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
          "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
          "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:22.663Z",
          "replyId": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
          "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
        },
        {
          "id": "1ea5cdcb-2f19-4b00-94e0-5b245bb91237",
          "content": "comment",
          "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
          "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
          "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:22.094Z",
          "replyId": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
          "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
        }
      ],
    "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
  }
]
```

So, What i get:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4",
    "content": "comment",
    "authorId": "a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782",
    "entityId": "91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111",
    "creatAt": "2021-10-04T08:43:04.391Z",
    "replyId": {},
    "type": "COMMENT_TYPE"
  }
]
```

The code with which I get all the comments:

```
@Get('/:entityId/comments')
  async getAll(@Param('entityId') entityId: string): Promise<any> {
    const comments = await this.commentRepository.find({
      where: { entityId: entityId, replyId: null },
      order: { id: 'DESC' },
    });
    return comments.map(entity => this.mapper(entity));
  }

private async getReply(commentId: string) {
    const reply = this.commentRepository.find({ where: { replyId: commentId } });
    reply.then(items => console.log(items));
    return reply.then(items => items.map(entity => this.mapper(entity)));
  }

  private mapper(entity: Comment): CommentDto {
    return new CommentDto(
      entity.id,
      entity.content,
      entity.authorId,
      entity.entityId,
      entity.creatAt,
      this.getReply(entity.id),
      entity.type,
    );
  }
```

In the getReply method I am using the console for debugging. This is what appears in it

```json
[
  Comment {
    id: 'd61e0049-9075-4f25-8f6d-65ed61e245a8',
    content: 'comment',
    authorId: 'a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782',
    entityId: '91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111',
    creatAt: 2021-10-04T08:43:21.271Z,
    replyId: '4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4',
    type: 'COMMENT_TYPE'
  },
  Comment {
    id: '1ea5cdcb-2f19-4b00-94e0-5b245bb91237',
    content: 'comment',
    authorId: 'a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782',
    entityId: '91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111',
    creatAt: 2021-10-04T08:43:22.094Z,
    replyId: '4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4',
    type: 'COMMENT_TYPE'
  },
  Comment {
    id: 'cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd',
    content: 'comment',
    authorId: 'a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782',
    entityId: '91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111',
    creatAt: 2021-10-04T08:43:22.663Z,
    replyId: '4f7b2bb3-b224-45d9-8093-9c0de7514bd4',
    type: 'COMMENT_TYPE'
  }
]
[]
[]
[
  Comment {
    id: 'dee96b97-cd45-4a09-a27d-985617cc5a16',
    content: 'comment',
    authorId: 'a30bfd0b-0519-4b4f-bbc5-04178f8af782',
    entityId: '91e22cb7-cb42-49a3-a5e7-8d111111',
    creatAt: 2021-10-04T08:43:35.204Z,
    replyId: 'cab2d3fd-7fba-4d02-a911-538246d92cfd',
    type: 'COMMENT_TYPE'
  }
]
[]
```

So, in the response I get the "replyId" field: = {}, there is an empty object. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Can you please reduce the code to the minimum needed (without any DB access code) as it seems that you already have models at hand? This will allow others to quickly test your code & help you with a solution

Comment: there seems to be no empty object in the console log.. do you mean empty array `[]` ?

Comment: @ParvSharma I copied everything that was in the IDE console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you don't have any type in CommentDto replyId.
2. Don't use then. Async / Await came up with to get rid of .then.

Solution:

```
@Get('/:entityId/comments')
  async getAll(@Param('entityId') entityId: string): Promise<CommentDto[]> {
    const comments = await this.commentRepository.find({
      where: { entityId: entityId, replyId: null },
      order: { id: 'DESC' },
    });
    return await Promise.all(comments.map(entity => this.mapper(entity)));
  }

private async getReply(commentId: string): Promise<CommentDto[]> {
    const reply = await this.commentRepository.find({ where: { replyId: commentId } });
    reply.then(items => console.log(items));
    return await Promise.all(reply.map(entity => this.mapper(entity)));
  }

  private mapper(entity: Comment): Promise<CommentDto> {
    return new CommentDto(
      entity.id,
      entity.content,
      entity.authorId,
      entity.entityId,
      entity.creatAt,
      await this.getReply(entity.id),
      entity.type,
    );
  }
```